# Assets folder is just returning main page

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to load in image in vue like so:

```
<img :src="./assets/example-banner"/>
```

It returns 200 but no image is shown:
[image]

When I follow the url in browser, to my surprise, I get the single page app instead of the resource! Can anyone explain what is going on here?

[image]

File structure is the standard

```
-assets/
--example-banner.jpg
-scr/
--components/
---DisplayImage.vue
```

Comment: your binding a non string. `<img src="./assets/example-banner.jpg"/>` then that will bundle the image into dist. look for banner.jpg in your codebase and see how that is done, it not clear of your setup.

Comment: btw that's not standard structure `assets` seems to be outside of `src`

Comment: Great simple advice @LawrenceCherone! I searched through the code base and it's using `require('../../assets/svg-main-logo.svg')`. Thank you helped a lot